# tried to create list...using data from firebase (stream builder) but got an error

Tags: firebase, flutter

error is:

```
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '[]'
Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.
Tried calling: []("quizImgUrl")
Found: []() => Map<String, dynamic>
```

trying to get image url in my code from:

```
ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return QuizTile(
                      imgUrl: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["quizImgUrl"],
                      desc: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["quizDesc"],
                      title: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["quizTitle"],
                    );
                  });
```

getting data from firebase as:

```
getQuizData() async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection("Quiz").snapshots();
  }
```

Comment: There is a get method for accessing the data in firestore plugin like snapshot.data.documents[index].data.get("quizImgUrl").

Comment: Thank you @ShahryarRafique for your suggestions. I can access the data using:  snapshot.data.document[index].get("quizImgUrl")

Comment: thanks for correcting my comment for future use.:-)

Answer (score 1):

user snapshot.data.docs instead.  They had many breaking changes in the latest updates to firebase packages.